# What is the difference between "I expect a call in the afternoon" and "I'm expecting a call in the afternoon"?

Tags: difference, present-continuous, present-simple

Would you tell me what is the difference between *I expect a call in the afternoon* and *I'm expecting a call in the afternoon*? Are both perfectly natural? If so, which one is more common?

Comment: A simple [Ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=i+expect+a+call%2Ci%27m+expecting+a+call&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20%27m%20expecting%20a%20call%3B%2Cc0) would have taken less time than writing this question. Closing for lack of research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're both perfectly natural. But -

The word **expect** can mean

**regard (something) as likely to happen**

(This is its meaning in "*I'm expecting a call in the afternoon.*")

But it can also mean

**require (something) as rightfully due or appropriate in the circumstances.**

Nelson's "England expects that every man will do his duty" uses this sense. He wasn't simply saying, "I daresay every man will do his duty": he was reminding his men that doing their duty was **required** of them.

Your sentence ***"I expect a call in the afternoon"*** suggests this second interpretation. It sounds a little irked.

[Definitions from [Lexico:expect](https://www.lexico.com/definition/expect).]

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27m%20expecting%20a%20call%2CI%20expect%20a%20call&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20%27m%20expecting%20a%20call%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20expect%20a%20call%3B%2Cc0) finds the less stroppy version to be commonest.

Comment: Basically agree. More "demanding" than "requiring" in the second sense. But within the first definition (i.e., not demanding something), "expecting" is more idiomatic in American English. If you were to say, "I have to go home now - I expect a visitor this afternoon," that would sound most unnatural. "I expect the Bengals to win the game tonight," on the other hand, purely as a prediction, is just as (if not more) idiomatic than "I'm expecting..."